# How to delete entries from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays

I'm trying to make a list of things (specifically Strings) that people have favorited, if they click 'add to Favorites' it executes this:

Class declaration:

```
ArrayList<String> favoritesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] factoids;
int counter;
```

onCreateBundle below:

```
Button favoritesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Resources res = getResources();
factoids = res.getStringArray(R.array.factsArray);
```

favoritesButton ActionListener below:

```
favoritesArray.add(factoid[counter]);
```

And then the ListView in the Favorites XML displays the new text, however, I'm stumped on what to do when they *un*-favourite the string. I would like the added Favorite text to be *removed* from the `favoritesArray`. How would I do this?

Comment: FavouritesArray is an arraylist. Arraylist has a remove method to do this. Removing from an array would be slightly more irritating

Comment: Why are you using an array based list and not a set (such as [`HashSet<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html))?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method provided by `ArrayList` called `.remove("your string here")` you can use.

For example, `arrListFav.remove("A")` will find and remove the first occurrence of the string `"A"` in your array list.

Comment: @420blazeit if you found this helpful please mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use (remove) as shown bellow:
for example you want to remove entity1 in the arraylist..

> favoritesArray.remove("entity1");